# What should I pass to ILayerFactory.Create for a WMSLayerFactory?

Tags: arcobjects, wms

I was expecting [ILayerFactory.CanCreate](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ILayerFactory_Interface/00120000073n000000/) to return true for an [IWMSLayerDescription](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IWMSLayerDescription_Interface/002v000000n2000000/).  I recursively traverse all the descriptions in a [WMS connection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IWMSServiceDescription_Interface/002v000000pz000000/) but CanCreate always returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expecting an `IName` object.

In your case, take a look at the `IWMSConnectionName` interface ( http://esriurl.com/1756 )
and the `WMSConnectionName` coclass ( http://esriurl.com/1755 ).